# How to check if a location is near a line between to points and coordinates on that line?

Tags: java, android, vector, gps, location

I have a factory with the three plants A,B and C. Each of that plant contains machines from 1 to 9 in a row. 
For each plant I know the location 1 and 9. None of the locations between them. 
Now the user can walk through the factory and save a location for each machine.

**Question:** How can I achieve that there is a line between the two edges 1 and 9? I would like to do that in Java Vectors. 
So the user could pass his current location and the program saves the nearest location that line. 
The aim is to get to know all the locations of the machines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dont really get the question clear. But think this might be of help

Create a Point Object with x cordinate is for plants and y cordinates for machines

Point location = new Point(1,1);//Means it is in Plant 1 on Machine 1

create a method to get where user is and store it

void setLocation(int plant, int location){

```
 location = new Point(plant, location);
```

}

Point getLocation(){

```
return location;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could make a 2d array of points, with the plants being the rows and machines being the columns, Point[plants][machines]. And then go through the array and give each Point a definite location.Then create a method called Search. In this search method, two parameters would be passed in, an x and y coordinate (the coordinates of your user).The search method would then iterate through the 2d array of points, and do the math to find the closest point to those passed in coordinates. Should be as simple as using the distance formula. Then you can just change the coordinates of the user to match that of the closest point found.